# Proof of Strong Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I want to show the Strong law of large numbers, That is, $$$$

$\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n} \rightarrow 0$(almost surely) $$$$ where each ${X_i}$ are independent random variable with finite third moments with same density function.

First I want to show under hypothesis that second moments are finite, that $$$$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nP(|X|>n)<\infty$
$$$$
But I don't know how to prove this statement. I tried to used weak theorem of large numbers but it seems like strong law can't be deduced from weak one.
$$$$Also, if I prove this, how can I proceed to show the Strong law of large numbers? I'm stuck here..
Actually, if someone helped me out just for the first part, namely proving $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nP(|X|>n)<\infty$, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nP(|X|>n)<\infty$ when $E(X^2)<\infty$, you can use the following results:

1. [Proof that $E[X^2]$ = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1) P(X\ge n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3243328/215011)
2. [Show $E[X] = \Sigma^\infty_{n=1}P[X\ge n]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1959806/215011)